# How to perform llama-index query when metadata are included to the documents

Tags: llama-index, qdrant

When adding metadata via every method listed [here](https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_modules/data_modules/documents_and_nodes/usage_documents.html#customizing-documents), the query does not return the correct node. Without metadata everything works fine.

adding `document.metadata = {'filename': '<doc_file_name>', 'id': '<doc_id>', 'subject': '<doc_subject>'}`, makes the query not working anymore.
Without passing metadata the retrieval from the query is fine and the result as expected.
Tried also to test via `excluded_embed_metadata_keys` and/or `excluded_llm_metadata_keys`, but nothing changed.

I'm using OpenAI completion_model="gpt-3.5-turbo" and embed_model="text-embedding-ada-002", and QdrantVectorStore

Answer (score 2):

Solution:
Change the syntax of Document following format. It will not send metadata to the llm for answering query

```
metadata_keys = list(metadata.keys()) # Your case ["filename", "id", "subject"]

doc = Document(id_=document_id, text=content, metadata=metadata, excluded_llm_metadata_keys=metadata_keys)

index.insert(doc)
```

Reference: https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.38/how_to/customization/custom_documents.html